# Can I connect an indoor water meter to water heater with PEX?

Tags: plumbing, water, pex, meter

So I have a water meter in our basement, connected to the city line via copper (it's also our electrical ground). From the meter is decades-old galvanized leading to a leaky shutoff (which I plan to replace). This galvanized goes forth through the house, with more recent connections to rooms made with PEX.

I moved the kitchen water line yesterday and we had a whole-house pressure drop. I believe corrosion has dislodged and become stuck in the line, so I plan to replace the remaining cold water galvanized with PEX.

My question with this: is there a reason to avoid PEX coming from the indoor meter? I'm thinking not, because it's cold water (I know I need 18" copper going into the water heater). I'd rather redo the line in PEX and go into a manifold if I can. But, I can do copper if there's a compelling reason to do so. I plan to check with the city on the meter itself, but thought I'd ask you-all first. :)

Comment: The only problem I see is the ground issue. Lots of new construction is PEX and many remodels. With an unknown grounding distance outside the house what happens when the main to the meter is replaced with plastic? I would want to install a new grounding rod just to be safe.

Comment: Our water heater installation manual (UK gas combi boiler) specifies that all pipes to and from it should be copper over at least 1 metre. I assume this is to avoid heat damage to plastic pipes and their rubber seals. Not sure about the meter. Over here many houses are supplied via MDPE pipe, not copper, but that's not the same as PEX. Grounding not a problem because the house is grounded via the electrical supply.

Answer (score 1):

IMO I would use something more robust like copper, galvanized, or brass from the meter to the shut off if exposed at all.  Then use PEX after the shutoff.

Just know PEX is not designed to be left exposed to UV light like the sun or physical abuse of any kind.  If receives much of either, I would use another material or get it covered up.

On that note, we see PEX all the time on both sides of a shutoff and you  probably (not entirely sure of your circumstances) can use PEX from your meter to your shutoff without any problems.